# react-router v4: prevent transition with custom hook instead of Prompt

Tags: javascript, react-router, history.js, html5-history

In `react-router` v3, I've been using [`router.setRouteLeaveHook`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md) to check if a form has unsaved changes, and if so return `false` to prevent the transition.  Then I would display a custom bootstrap modal dialog with 3 buttons: Save Changes, Discard Changes, and Stay Here.

I can't use `react-router` v4's `Prompt` component to do this because it's not possible to customize the buttons shown in a browser confirm dialog.  It seems like they got rid of any way to cancel the transition in favor of only allowing you to ask the user to approve the transition in a browser confirm dialog.

I tried looking in the code for `Prompt` but [it just passes the dialog message to `history`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Prompt.js#L32), so that doesn't give me any idea how to set up a v3-style route leave hook.

Is it even possible anymore or did the `react-router` devs intentionally decide to remove this capability this for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `Prompt` to show custom dialogue. Credit and detailed explanation [here](https://michaelchan-13570.medium.com/using-react-router-v4-prompt-with-custom-modal-component-ca839f5faf39).

`Prompt` requires a message prop, here we can use a custom function for a dialogue and it should return `false` to prevent navigation.

```
const BlockingPage = () => {
  const [block, setBlock] = useState(true);
  
  const blockedNavigation = (nLocation) => {
    //nLocation gives the next location object
    
    /**
      * Your custom logic
      *
    **/
    
    //required to block navigation
    return false
  } 

  return(
    <div>
      <Prompt when={block} message={blockedNavigation}/>
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: Ah cool, I'm not sure this was a feature when I submitted OP

Comment: Docs at https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Prompt sort of hint this, but it's missing the fact that you can `return false` to block navigation

Answer (score 3):

According to [the history package docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#customizing-the-confirm-dialog), you can replace `window.confirm` with anything you like:

> By default, window.confirm is used to show prompt messages to the user. If you need to override this behavior (or if you're using createMemoryHistory, which doesn't assume a DOM environment), provide a getUserConfirmation function when you create your history object.

So if you want to use your own dialog, something like this should see you through:

```
const history = createHistory({
  getUserConfirmation(message, callback) {
    showMyCustomDialog(message)
      .then(result => callback(result === 'The YES button'))
  }
})
```

This means that whatever `getUserConfirmation` message you set is set for the entire session, but you could abstract it out to your navigation  blocking layer that holds additional details for your dialog, e.g. title, button text, colours etc.

Alternatively, you could hijack the `message` argument and use it for dialog configuration, though that may smell a bit nasty. But it's not a perfect system so anything you do will probably be a bit of a hack.

React Router v4 allows you to pass this method through when you create your router (see [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/getUserConfirmation-func)):

```
<BrowserRouter getUserConfirmation={yourConfirmationFunction} />
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't discovered that!  It's certainly true, anything I do will probably be a hack.  Which was not the case for the old route leave hooks.

Comment: One barely hacky approach would be to use `message` as an object key, and set up a dictionary of possible navigation blockers. For example, `blockers = {myBlocker: cb => dialog.then(cb)}` and then in your user confirmation function, call `blockers[message](callback)`. I've recently done the v3 => v4 upgrade and found I only ever user one dialog, and sometimes just block navigation completely (e.g. when a modal is shown), so baking the dialog code into the confirmation function was enough for me. I'm sure the project would take a PR if you're up for expanding its capabilities!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. react-router-v4 uses a package called [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) that in turns uses the HTML5 history api. The history api only notifies you when you hit the back button (onpopstate), If you think about it this makes lots of sense, since you would not want to give a website the power of not letting you move between pages.

The best you can do is the [window onbeforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), that creates a prompt for you asking confirmation from the user, but this is exactly what react-router exposes for you to use.

You might get some of the functionality you want by monkey-patching react-router's internal history object, and that way you can add your own behaviour. But there is a caveat, this is only going to work when you react-router's `<Link />` component and friends, so you will not be able to intercept refreshes and other things you may want.

If you want to go that route, let me know I can give you some insight or code examples about how might that work and I will update my answer.

Comment: but how does react-router-v3 prevent transitions?  It also uses history so unless they removed this functionality from history, I don't get what you're saying.